# Birkhoff Method for Harmonic Oscillator Perturbation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism, perturbation-theory

**Problem:** Given Hamiltonian $$H = \frac12 (p^{2}+q^{2})+q^{3}-3qp^{2}$$ make a perturbative canonical transformation $(q,p) \rightarrow (Q,P)$ such that the new Hamiltonian, apart from terms of degree greater than 4 in $Q$ and $P$, is of the form $$\bar{H}(Q,P)= \frac12 (P^{2}+Q^{2})+c(P^{2}+Q^{2})^{2}$$ by using Birkhoff's version of canonical perturbation theory in which one first makes a canonical transformation to complex coordinates $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$, where $a= \frac{(q-ip)}{\sqrt{2}}, a^{\dagger}=\frac{(p-iq)}{\sqrt{2}}.$

**My Issue:** In my previous use of the Birkhoff perturbation method (which I see more commonly referred to as [Birkhoff normal form](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=Birkhoff+normal+form)) the goal is to get the Hamiltonian into a power series of the action, $bb^{\dagger}$, where $(a,a^{\dagger})\rightarrow(b,b^{\dagger})$, and I don't see how to get the following transformation to give the Hamiltonian in the desired form.

**Work So Far:**
After substituting $(q,p) \rightarrow (a,a^{\dagger})$, where $q=\frac{(a+ia^{\dagger})}{\sqrt{2}}, p=\frac{(ia+a^{\dagger})}{\sqrt{2}}$, $$H(a,a^{\dagger})=iaa^{\dagger} + \sqrt{2}(a^{3}-ia^{\dagger 3})$$
I then chose a generating function $F(a,b^{\dagger}) = ab^{\dagger}+S(a,b^{\dagger})$, where $S(a,b^{\dagger})$ is a cubic polynomial. Then $$a^{\dagger} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial a} = b^{\dagger}+\frac{\partial S(b,b^{\dagger})}{\partial b} + \text{higher order terms}$$
$$b = \frac{\partial F}{\partial b^{\dagger}} = a+\frac{\partial S(b,b^{\dagger})}{\partial b^{\dagger}} + \text{higher order terms}$$
Then I think I'm doing something wrong with keeping track of the higher order terms here.

I'd really appreciate any guidance in understanding this problem, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coordinate transformation, from $(q,p)\to(a,a^{\dagger})$ seems a little funky monkey.

I would let

$$a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(q+ip); \quad \quad a^{\dagger}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(q-ip),$$

so that

$$q=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(a+a^{\dagger}); \quad p=-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(a-a^{\dagger}).$$

Next, we let

$$a=\epsilon b+\epsilon^2 d; \quad a^{\dagger}=\epsilon b^{\dagger}+\epsilon^2 d^{\dagger},$$

where $\epsilon$ is a small parameter. We put this into the Hamiltonian and keep all terms to $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^4)$.

The point is to get rid of the third order interaction terms.

This constrains the third order condition:

$$\epsilon^3: \quad \sqrt{2}b^3+\sqrt{2}b^{\dagger3}+b^{\dagger}d+bd^{\dagger}=0.$$

This implies

$$d=-\sqrt{2}b^{\dagger 2},$$
with $d^{\dagger}$ following trivially.

Therefore, the Hamiltonian becomes
$$H=bb^{\dagger} +c b^2b^{\dagger 2},$$
(with c=-10). The coordinates $(P,Q)$ can then be easily written in terms of $(b,b^{\dagger})$.